# External URL with app-launch hangs during on-device testing

Tags: bixby

I have a button that links out to an external URL by using an action that triggers a result-view with an app-launch.

Button:

```
input-cell {
  label ("#{value(button.text)}")
  on-click {
    intent {
      goal: FetchUrl
      value-set: UrlConcept { $expr(button.value) }
    }
  }
}
```

Action:

```
action (FetchUrl) {
  description (Fetches External Url)
  type (Constructor)
  collect {
    input (url) {
      type (UrlConcept)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
  }
  output (UrlConcept) {
    evaluate {
      UrlConcept$expr (url) 
    }
  }
}
```

Model:

```
text (UrlConcept) {
  description (External Url)
}
```

Result View:

```
result-view {
  match: UrlConcept (this) {
    min(Required) max (One)
  }
  render {
    nothing
  }
  app-launch {
    payload-uri {
      template ("#{value(this)}")
    }
  }
}
```

This works as expected in the Bixby Simulator - clicking the button results in the message 'User successfully exits Bixby, redirecting to an app', and I can view the logs and see the correct URI.

However, this fails when tested on multiple physical devices.  Clicking the button results in Bixby hanging forever.

Comment: This issue is currently being investigated by our team. We'll update this post once we know more!

Comment: Hey Cory, Can you attempt this again? I've just confirmed that `app-launch` is working as intended.

Comment: Can confirm that this is fixed